# Why put @Repository on top of Spring Data JPA interfaces?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Very often I see code like the following:

```
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>
```

And my question is why do we need this `@Repository` annotation?
I understand why `@Repository` exist, and why we may need to put in on top of some class.
But classes didn't inherit annotations from interfaces in Java. Of course, I can miss something about Spring 'magic', but the default JPA implementation class is the following:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements JpaRepositoryImplementation<T, ID>
```

and it contains `@Repository` on its own, so why we need it on our interface?

Spring Data documentation also didn't say anything about `@Repository` in the related section, but some occasional examples from the other parts of documentation contain code fragment where `@Repository` is present, so maybe something was changed over time?

Answer (score 1):

> I can miss something about Spring 'magic'

Most likely you miss `@EnableJpaRepositories`. From the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html):
"Will scan the package of the annotated configuration class for Spring Data repositories **by default.**"

> why we need it on our interface?

We don't. It is redundant to annotate the interfaces/classes with `@Repository` which extend/implement `JpaRepository` or some other predefined interfaces extending `Repository`, both because of `@EnableJpaRepositories` and the fact that they extend/implement `Repository` interface.

Relevant quote from the [Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/Repository.html) (not `@Repository`): "General purpose is to hold type information as well as being able to **discover interfaces that extend this one during classpath scanning for easy Spring bean creation**."

Now why then `SimpleJpaRepository` is annotated with `@Repository`? Because it is in the different package than the (once again the same [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/config/EnableJpaRepositories.html)) "package of **the annotated configuration class**".

Comment: `@EnableJpaRepositories` does not have anything to do with `@Repository`. I suggest you re-read the question again

Comment: In this particular example it definitely has! They annotated ```SimpleJpaRepository```, because ```EnableJpaRepository``` cannot cover the package where this class resides. Imagine that you want to use ```SimpleJpaRepository``` directly, how would you possibly do that without ```@Repository``` on top of this class?

Comment: your comment is about the annotation on a _class_, while the question is about an _interface_. I will repeat `@Repository` has nothing to do with `@EnableJPARepositories`. The first is a fancy `@Component`, the second is where scanning of extensions of spring jpa specific interfaces exist.

Answer (score 1):

It is rather interesting that the [spring official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference) shows `@Repository` on an `interface` in two different examples; though there is simply no need for this.

For the fun of it, I scanned our source-code (around 100 micro-services) and I found *too many* places where `@Repository` is present on the interface. I think it happens because people are facing some types of problems (like `No qualifying bean of type...`) and just start adding annotations everywhere they can, in order for the code to work.

I even doubted myself thinking that may be indeed spring boot in the recent versions did some (weird) magic, but no. After some tests it just showed the obvious : `@Repository` is useless on interfaces. In theory, Spring could find out that a certain interface extends its `JPARepository`, see that it is annotated with `@Repository` and apply the same to some class that it would provide as a `@Bean`. But

- implementations of `JPARepository` already have that annotation
- this would make little sense anyway